# How to limit a max value in a cell?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am setting up a new spreadsheet in google spreadsheets and I need to set a max value because it can surpass that number.

I am currently using this formula -> `=SUMPRODUCT(D17:D33)` and that sum can be more than 50, and if that's true, I want to limit to 50.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something simple like:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(D17:D33)>50; 50; SUMPRODUCT(D17:D33))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=min(50;sumproduct(D17:D33))
```